# Unable to add a row to a HTML table dynamically

Tags: internet-explorer, dom, ihtmldocument2

I am unable to add a row to a HTML table dynamically. I am using `IHtmlDocument2` to create `tr` and `td` elements and `IHtmlElement` to set attributes and `IHtmlDomNode` to add created node to the document hierarchy.

Please anyone help me to solve the above problem.

I am traversing through the document when I get the `tr` tag I have created the `tr` element using `CreateElement`, then I use `InsertBefore` to insert it into the document but it's not working.

I've tried for one week but didn't get anything working.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you start using a JavaScript framework such a [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/). Either of these will allow you to achieve the functionality with one line of JavaScript code regardless of which browser you have. Using Prototype for example:

```
$$('table#mytable').insert({bottom: '<tr><td>some html</td></tr>'})
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery it's

```
$('table#mytable').append('<tr><td>some html</td></tr>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably a little late. I've been recently replacing a .Net app that used to use the old DHTML control, but to get it to work under Windows 7 I've had to replace this with the WebBrowser control which represents a significant step backward in functionality. I've been using the underlying IHtmlDocument2 interface to work with it. In this case I "cheated" and just built the table up in raw HTML, pasted it to the clipboard as HTML, then use execCommand("Paste") of the interface. This was wrapped within a clipboard preserver so the original clipboard state was restored.